# For loop of sockets with threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, foreach

i'm building a Desktop Application that uses sockets to connect to a server. I have a list of users and i need each user to be connected independently to that server

foreach loop:

```
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    Connect(account, server);
}
```

The thing is, imagine i have 200 accounts, and Connect() takes 2 seconds to run, it would take more then 6 minutes to go thought the foreach loop.

Connect Function Sample:

```
private void Connect(User user, Server server)
{
    connection = new Connection($"{server.Ip}:{server.Port.ToString()}", user);
    connection.Connect(); // await
    connection.WaitToConnect(); // await
    connection.SendData(); // await 
    connection.SendAnotherData(); // await
    connection.WaitCallBack(); // await
    if(connection.everythingFine) // From here connection is "completed" but can't be closed
    {
    }

    // Trigger my event handler on disconnect
    connection.Disconnected += disconnectionHandler; 
}
```

As Connect() is sync and creates a persistent connection with event handlers and etc. I'm afraid using threads and what it could cause to my socket connection and event handlers.

Edit:

**Question is**: How can I implement threading on my foreach loop in this situation?

Comment: Language? C# it would be best to use parallel for each. It will use a thread pool/task pool. Tasks are thinner than threads. You might try a non-blocking thread safe list or connection, too.

Comment: Ideally, *don't* think about threads, in this modern age. Look at async methods, and have some kind of "state" object for each client instead, that callbacks/continuations for the async calls have access to. Let the framework/OS worry about giving you threads, scheduling, etc.

Comment: Is Connection a custom class built upon sockets or something like that?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever would you mind writing a brief code explanation? I'm a Javascript developer so async is my place, but i just started C# 2 days ago for a personal project, so i'm just diving into it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to be afraid of threads.  I don't know your code well to suggest a more sophisticated approach, but you can just fire up a thread for every account:

```
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    var t = new Thread((aObj) => Connect ((Account)aObj, server));
    t.Start(account);
}
```

Comment: Tasks and await async is lighter and would work just as well.

Comment: Not really convinced that in his case they would.  If `connection.WaitCallBack(); ` blocks until a call is received or something like this, he will exhaust the thread pool quickly and _nothing_ will work.

Comment: Connection appears a custom class.  At this point we do not know wether is has async variants orperhaps polling or wether is can be altered to support these.  The question lead me to beieve async variants are available.

Comment: This is pure speculation.  Since we don't know more, I prefer to stay on the safe side and advise threads.  Of course, best is that the author sheds more light. :-)

Comment: agreed.  Shall we VtC until we know more?